# Mule SAX parse exception during deployment

Tags: mule-studio, mule-component, mulesoft

I am getting the below exception in Anypoint studio with same HttpListener

Using the below runtime environment.

Runtime: 4.1.4
Any pointIDE  :7.4.2

Is there any compatibility between the IDE and runtime?

Any suggestion on this?

Thanks.

- Initializing app 'firstmule'                             +
  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  INFO  2020-02-24 12:04:51,481 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.manager.DefaultExtensionManager: Registering extension ee (version: 4.1.4 vendor: MuleSoft, Inc. )
  INFO  2020-02-24 12:04:51,481 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.manager.DefaultExtensionManager: Registering extension mule (version: 4.1.4 vendor: MuleSoft, Inc. )
  INFO  2020-02-24 12:04:55,990 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.manager.DefaultExtensionManager: Registering extension Sockets (version: 1.1.5 vendor: Mulesoft )
  INFO  2020-02-24 12:04:55,993 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.manager.DefaultExtensionManager: Registering extension HTTP (version: 1.5.6 vendor: Mulesoft )
  INFO  2020-02-24 12:04:59,750 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Disposing RegistryBroker
  ERROR 2020-02-24 12:04:59,750 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
  org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleRuntimeException: There was '1' error while parsing the given file 'firstmule.xml'.
  Full list:
  org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 9; cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'flow' is not complete. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor}' is expected.

INFO  2020-02-24 12:04:59,765 [WrapperListener_start_runner] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.application.DefaultMuleApplication: App 'firstmule' never started, nothing to dispose of
ERROR 2020-02-24 12:04:59,781 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArchiveDeployer: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Failed to deploy artifact 'firstmule', see below         +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
org.mule.runtime.deployment.model.api.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifact [firstmule]
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleRuntimeException: org.mule.runtime.deployment.model.api.DeploymentInitException: MuleRuntimeException: There was '1' error while parsing the given file 'firstmule.xml'.
Full list:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 9; cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'flow' is not complete. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor}' is expected.

Caused by: org.mule.runtime.deployment.model.api.DeploymentInitException: MuleRuntimeException: There was '1' error while parsing the given file 'firstmule.xml'.
Full list:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 9; cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'flow' is not complete. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor}' is expected.

Caused by: org.mule.runtime.core.api.config.ConfigurationException: There was '1' error while parsing the given file 'firstmule.xml'.
Full list:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 9; cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'flow' is not complete. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor}' is expected.

Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleRuntimeException: There was '1' error while parsing the given file 'firstmule.xml'.
Full list:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 9; cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'flow' is not complete. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor}' is expected.

INFO  2020-02-24 12:04:59,781 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Mule is up and kicking (every 5000ms)                    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2020-02-24 12:05:00,731 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Started ServerConnector@44510ad1{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:56978}
INFO  2020-02-24 12:05:00,731 [WrapperListener_start_runner]

Comment: No, there isn't, though a newest version of Mule is recommended to avoid many known issues. Mule 4.2.2 is the latest and best. Please attach the XML file that produces the error to understand if it is a namespace issue.

Comment: I am having this same issue. It works fine in Anypoint Studio but fails in maven.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you have already sorted it out but based on the error, seems like the Mule app does not have any connector in the flow "process area".

Thus, the Mule app will fail because it just contain an HTTP Listener connector in the flow "source area".

By adding for instance, a "Log" connector or a "Se Payload" connector on the right of the HTTP Listener, the flow "process area" wont be empty, and therefore the Mule app will be able to deploy and run successfully.